# What word(s) describe a woman's voice as "sexy"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word (or two words) to describe a woman's voice that is "sexy" in a slightly deep, smooth, alluring way.  The best I could come up with is *mellifluous*, but I'm looking for something simpler...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

maybe "Sultry"? It's not specifically used to describe a voice, but it's a common use.

```
(of a person, esp. a woman) attractive in a way that suggests a passionate nature.
```

Comment: The first word that came to mind was "sultry" for me too. Other words like "silky", "raspy", "chesty" also occurred to me, but they do not exactly fit the OP's description.

Answer (score 14):

You could say she has a *sultry* voice.

See [entry 2b](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sultry):

> exciting or capable of exciting strong sexual desire

Comment: Huh. Weird that you answered a minute before, but got half the votes.

Comment: And now I see someone has come along and down-voted my answer, perhaps thinking it happened later than the accepted one.

Answer (score 8):

"A *seductive* voice" sounds good.

Answer (score 8):

A **husky** voice?

> **Husky voice is the key to seduction** *—headline in [Hindustan Times](http://www.hindustantimes.com/Husky-voice-is-the-key-to-seduction/Article1-547439.aspx)*

*Husky* has the specific connotations of *deep* and *alluring* that you’re asking for — though maybe not so much of *smooth*.

Comment: Where I come from, "husky" means raspy and masculine.  Depending on one's tastes this could be attractive I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, my dictionary says "(of a voice or utterance) sounding low-pitched and slightly hoarse" – this doesn't sound particularly smooth or feminine

Comment: I agree with "husky." I see this word used in exactly this way with some frequency.

Answer (score 5):

Moving beyond simple adjectives, there’s a long tradition of using similes, especially food and drink, for sexy female voices:

- like honey
- like Bourbon
- like (melted) chocolate
- like melted butter
- like (fine) (red) wine
- like velvet

These are especially popular for describing jazz and soul singers singers — I remember some Nina Simone and Ells Fitzgerald liner notes from the 60’s and 70’s with great examples, which I wish I could find online…

Answer (score 4):

Smokey. Often used to refer to singers, but conveys the sense without the "weight" of husky or the overtness of sultry.

Answer (score 3):

> She has a tantalizing voice.

As reported by the NOAD, the meaning of *tantalize* is *excite the senses or desires of someone*.

Answer (score 3):

Some words that come to mind:

Sultry, Sexy, Attractive, arousing, come-hither, delicious, luscious, appealing, captivating, heavenly, fetching.

Answer (score 0):

***Mellow***
*(esp. of sound, taste, and color) Pleasantly smooth or soft; free from harshness.*

> He was hypnotized by the mellow tone of her voice